# Create Table and Migrate Data

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I am a newbie to database programming and has a question.

In the C++ application that am working, there's a Oracle DB. One of the table is called USR_INFO. It has multiple columns like,

```
 1. U_INFO_ID
 2. U_INFO_FIRST_NAME
 3. U_INFO_LAST_NAME
 4. U_INFO_ADDRESS
 5. U_INFO_AGE
 6. U_INFO_LAST_LOGIN_DATE
 7. U_INFO_LAST_LOGIN_TIME
```

Now i want to create a new table called USR_LOG_INFO, and add 3 columns to it called,

```
 1. U_INFO_ID
 2. U_INFO_LAST_LOGIN_DATE
 3. U_INFO_LAST_LOGIN_TIME
```

And then migrate the data for same columns from USR_INFO to similar columns in USR_LOG_INFO.

Basically there are 2 steps involved here.

1.Create new table called USR_LOG_INFO

2.Migrate column data from USR_INFO to USR_LOG_INFO

Can somebody give me SQL commands to do above 2 steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy answer.. don't..

```
alter table USR_INFO rename USR_LOG_INFO;
alter table USR_LOG_INFO add (U_INFO_ID                NUMBER,
                              U_INFO_LAST_LOGIN_DATE    DATE,
                              U_INFO_LAST_LOGIN_TIME    DATE);
```

done.

if you really want to do it your way.

```
create table USR_LOG_INFO as
   select * 
        , to_number(NULL) U_INFO_ID 
        , to_date(null)  U_INFO_LAST_LOGIN_DATE    
        , to_date(null) U_INFO_LAST_LOGIN_TIME
   from USR_INFO;

drop table USR_INFO;
```

and finally 
why do you have separate date/time columns
you might be better off just using a TIMESTAMP column and extracting the date and/or time when you need it.

Comment: Oracle DATEs include the time. You only need TIMESTAMP if you want fractions of a second, for like doing stock trades or things that VERY time sensitive.

Comment: true.. you still only need 1 column, not 2.  but i feel that if you are doing auditing events then a timestamp is perfect for that.  i now use `timestamp with timezone` columns whenever it makes sense, which is useuall if it has any time component.. and mainly use date column with no time ie `date = trunc(date)`

Answer (score 0):

Another 2-step approach:

```
create table USR_LOG_INFO
as
  select * 
  from USR_INFO;
```

then follow user Shoelace's advice on adding the extra columns with the 2nd `alter table` command.

I avoided the `drop table` step because, from reading the OP's question, it was not clear as to whether or not the OP wanted the original table to remain or to be removed.